# Send a fax from computer to printer?

Tags: software-rec, printer, fax

Ultimately, I need to be able to send a fax. I would prefer to send it via some online service, but I can't find any good free ones.

I dusted off an old printer/faxer/scanner combo we bought YEARS ago. It's an HP officejet 4215. I would like to be able to send pages from the computer to the machine via usb without printing them out. Is this possible?

Actually, if you could answer any of the following:

1. Can I send free faxes online with my own cover page?
2. Can I send a fax from my computer without printing out the content?

Comment: Have you tried asking HP yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Yes, they asked me to power cycle my computer and fax machine...

Comment: Did they bother telling you to install the drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows, you should be able to use [Windows Fax and Scan](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-XM/windows7/Send-a-fax-with-Windows-Fax-and-Scan) to send any faxes from your computer with a connected fax machine.

Comment: How? The two options for sending a fax with Windows Fax and Scan are to connect the computer to a telephone line, or be connected to a fax server.

Comment: Do you not have a telephone line available?

Answer (score 0):

Symantec WinFax will do cover pages and send stuff without printing and rescanning it, but not free – they do offer a free trial though.

Comment: What? WinFax has been discontinued for more than five years now.